# Detect click on unclickable button c#

Tags: c#, winforms, button, onclick

I want to display message that button is unclickable (I have used Enabled option, button1.Enabled = false/true; ). Does anyone know how to detect if button is clicked, when it is unclickable in order to display error message "Button is unclickable...".
Windows forms, C#

Comment: Well the whole point of being unabled, is so you can't click on it...

Comment: what about keeping the button enabled and only show the message in click event ?

Comment: When you click a disabled Button, the Click event is handled by its Parent Container. You can use [ChildWindowFromPoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-childwindowfrompoint) to get the handle of the child Control that was clicked and compare with the handle of the Parent (which you used in the function call). If the handles don't match, a disabled child was clicked. You can then show a ToolTip at the Click location -- To skip invisible Controls (to only consider disabled Controls), use `ChildWindowFromPointEx`.

Comment: Note that the `EventArgs` of a `Click` handler is actually a `MouseEventArgs`, so the Click position is `var pos = ((MouseEventArgs)e).Location;`

Answer (score 0):

Whenever a standard control doesn't behave in exactly the way that need it to, all we usually have to do is make our own version that *inherits* the standard control so that we can **make it do whatever we want**. Your question offers a great reason for doing that because a normally a disabled `Button` is not going to fire a `Click` or a `MouseDown` event.

Here is a guideline example for a custom `Button` that:

1. Intercepts the `Enabled` property by declaring it `new`.
2. Leaves the base class button always responsive because it's always enabled.
3. Paints the control as dimmed if disabled.
4. Suppresses the firing of the `Click` event if disabled, and fires `DisabledClick` instead.

*Look in the Title Bar to see when the button is clicked.*

[image: button with disabled option]

---

**`ButtonWithDisabledOption class`**

```
class ButtonWithDisableOption : Button
{
    bool _enabled = true;
    public new bool Enabled
    {
        get => _enabled;
        set
        {
            if (!Equals(_enabled, value))
            {
                _enabled = value;
                OnEnabledChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }
    }
    protected override void OnEnabledChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnEnabledChanged(e);
        if(Enabled)
        {
            ForeColor = SystemColors.ControlText;
            BackColor = SystemColors.Control;
            FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Standard;
        }
        else
        {
            ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(191, 191, 191);
            BackColor = Color.FromArgb(204, 204, 204);
            FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
        }
    }
    protected override void OnClick(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Enabled)
        {
            base.OnClick(e);
        }
        else
        {
            DisabledClick?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
    public event EventHandler DisabledClick;
}
```

---

**MainForm.Designer.cs**

Be sure to replace `Button` references with `ButtonWithDisabledOption`.

```
private void InitializeComponent()
{
    // this.buttonWithDisableOption = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
    this.buttonWithDisableOption = new button_with_disabled_option.ButtonWithDisableOption();
    ...
}

// private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;
private button_with_disabled_option.ButtonWithDisableOption buttonWithDisableOption;
```

---

**TEST**

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        buttonWithDisableOption.Enabled = checkBoxButtonEnabled.Checked = true;

        // Button events
        buttonWithDisableOption.Click += buttonWithDisableOption_Click;
        buttonWithDisableOption.DisabledClick += buttonWithDisableOption_DisabledClick;

        // CheckBox events
        checkBoxButtonEnabled.CheckedChanged += checkBoxButtonEnabled_CheckedChanged;
    }
    private void checkBoxButtonEnabled_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        buttonWithDisableOption.Enabled = checkBoxButtonEnabled.Checked;
    }
    private void buttonWithDisableOption_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Title bar
        Text = $"Button Click {_tstcount++} (Enabled)";  
    }
    private void buttonWithDisableOption_DisabledClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Title bar
        Text = $"Button Click {_tstcount++} (Disabled)";
        MessageBox.Show("Button is unclickable");
    }
    int _tstcount = 1;
}
```

Comment: [Clone](https://github.com/IVSoftware/button-with-disabled-option.git) this sample.